# xvfb-run: open separate tabs in the same screen

Tags: centos7, xvfb, selenium-server

I am starting the selenium standalone server to run some UI tests in headless mode using Xvfb on a CentOS7 machine.
Below is my command to start the server:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 3024x1964x24" java -jar selenium-server-4.8.0.jar standalone --host 0.0.0.0
```

The tests have a concurrency of 5 and all 5 instances of the tests start in the expected resolution of 3024x1964.

However, when one of the tests try to open a new tab and perform some operations on it, the tab is opening in a lower resolution (probably the default 800x600, which means its opening in a different screen).

So, is there a way to ensure that the new tab is opening in the same screen/resolution as the parent tab?